# How to upload file to hidden input with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload a file from system to webdriver. I have to automate a web application and it contains a drag and drop area for uploading files from the local system. I found that there is an input tag and it is hidden. I searched some articles but in every one they are using "document.getElementById(..)" and this one is not working for me.

my html code is like this

```
<div class="_ay_g1" role="textbox"><input type="file" tabindex="-1" multiple="true" class="_ay_g1"></div>
     <input type="file" tabindex="-1" multiple="true" class="_ay_g1">
</div>
```

I tried

```
browser.execute_script("document.querySelector(\"primaryContainer > div:nth-child(7) > div > div._n_T > div > div._n_X > div:nth-child(3) > div > div._n_Y > div.allowTextSelection > div > div._mcp_T2._mcp_W2 > div._mcp_U2._mcp_W2.customScrollBar.scrollContainer._mcp_Y2 > div > div._mcp_d1.ms-border-color-neutralLight > div._mcp_e1.ms-bg-color-white > div:nth-child(2) > div._mcp_z1.ms-border-color-themeTertiary > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div._ay_g1 > div:nth-child(1) > input\").style.display='block'""")

input_h = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"primaryContainer\"]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input")
input_h.send_keys(path)
```

for the document.querySelector part I copied JS path from the html but it didn't work.

How can I upload a file from local in this input?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Python-Selenium framework, there's a method: `self.show_file_choosers()`, which turns hidden file-upload `input` fields into visible ones. There's an example test that uses that here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_show_file_choosers.py

Once the field is visible, you can use standard commands for uploading files, eg. `send_keys()`.

Sample code for making a hidden input field visible on a site:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class FileUpload(BaseCase):
    def test_show_file_choosers(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.io/apps/img_upload")
        self.wait_for_element('img[alt="ImgBB"]')
        choose_file_selector = 'input[type="file"]'
        uploaded_image = "#anywhere-upload-queue li.queue-item"
        self.assert_element_not_visible(choose_file_selector)
        self.show_file_choosers()
        self.highlight(choose_file_selector)
        self.assert_element(choose_file_selector)
        # ...
```